# Find which embedded files take large size in a swf

Tags: apache-flex, flash

How do I find which all embedded files are taking up sizes in a specific swf file. I am looking for something like [Windirstat](http://windirstat.info/) for swf files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to use Flex SDK 4.5 which gives [size report](https://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Size%20Report/).